React RouterDom doesnt work on outlet and subroutes
I have this following route config
export function App() {

  return (
    <>
        <PrimeReactProvider>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />}/>
                  <Route path="/painel" element={<Painel/>}/>
                     <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashBoard/>}/>
                  <Route/>
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </PrimeReactProvider>
    </>
  )
}

Inside the Painel component I have:
export const Painel = ()=>{
    return(
        <div>
            <PainelMenu/>
            <Outlet/>
        </div>
    )
}

The problem is when /painel/dashboard is accessed not content is shown. What I tried:

Switch /painel to /painel/

Switch /painel to /painel/*

Switch path="dashboard" to path="/painel/dashboard" it rendered the
component  but not the  component

Removing browser router


I see no error in my usage following the docs https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet

I suspect you've a typo where you have prematurely closed the Route tag, e.g. <Route path="/painel" element={<Painel/>} /> then have a later empty route, e.g. <Route />. Update your code to properly nest the dashboard route. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Your slash placement is causing this.
Instead of:
<Route path="/painel" element={<Painel/>}/>
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashBoard/>}/>
<Route/>

try this:
<Route path="/painel" element={<Painel/>}>
    <Route path="dashboard" element={<DashBoard/>}/>
</Route>

